# асинхронный запрос okhttp android

Tags: java, android, асинхронность, okhttp

в активити при нажатии кнопки "войти" вызывается запрос `post` запрос на авторизацию, после которого при удачной авторизации, происходит переход на другую активити.Но тк запрос происходит асинхронно, активити запускается в то время, пока происходит запрос и приложение крашится. Как можно решить эту проблему, чтобы активити открывалась только после завершения запроса и обработки данных ответа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно ответ в вопросе - запускайте активити только после успешной авторизации. Т.е. в колбэке асинхронной задачи, после обработки ответа сервера.

Comment: Т.е. внутри onResponse вызвать новую Активити?

Comment: @Arina, да, всё верно

Comment: Когда внутри onResponse пытаюсь вызвать Активити Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NavActivity.class); startActivity(intent) Приложение вылетает

Comment: @Arina, когда у вас что-то падает - надо указывать на какой строке и с какой ошибкой падает. Иначе гадать можно долго - ошибка может быть в 47 местах и по 42 причинам.

Comment: @Arina, видимо у Вас помимо асинхронности проблема есть, стектрейс падения покажите.